# Why can not my client get socket.io.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am learning to use socket.io, but when I add

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
```

<strike>in my client, and I add code:</strike>

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('------------connection');
});
```

in `app.js`, but my client do get 404 error when trying to get `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

I chage my code to :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

var userlist = {};

io.on('connection', function(data){
  console.log('------------connection');
  socket.name = data.user;

  if (!userlist[data.user]) {
    userlist[data.user] = data.user;
  };

  io.emit("online", { userlist: userlist, user: data.user});
});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

and I also have the code as follow in my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    // other code
}
```

Comment: In your server code, what is `app` in the above code?  And, can you show your `.listen()` call?  You aren't showing enough for things to be fully initialized so I'm not sure where things go wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 `app.js` is generate router by Express Framework, you already got my question, I use `var io = require('socket.io')(server);` instead of `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry my problem still remain, I have change my question, can you give me some suggestion again?

Comment: Your web server needs to be started with `server.listen(port)`.  The socket.io documentation shows you the basics here: http://socket.io/docs/.  Why don't you just copy one of those to get started.

Comment: @jfriend00 but my express framework has already bind a port, so I think I should just use `var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);`

Comment: Honestly, I can't help you if you aren't going to show all the relevant code.  There has to be a `server.listen(port)` to actually start your web server and to me that is the first issue to establish.  The server can be started either directly with http server object of, if you are using Express, you can ask Express to do it for you.  But, I can't tell if your server is actually running or not.  You do not show any code that actually starts it.  `io.listen()` does not start the web server - that just attaches the socket.io library to an existing web server object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72287/discussion-between-roger-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @jfriend00 my office can not push code to github, so I change the question again, this time it is the most part of code.